# FullForm in Linux Command Line with -noprompt

Tags: output-formatting, command-line

I am looking for a way to get the output of FullForm in Command Line under Linux (Debian) using -noprompt argument.

Example :
What I have : `a+b*c`

What I want : `Plus[a, Times[b, c]]`.

I can have it like this (without -noprompt but I get useless text)

```
#  echo 'FullForm[a+b*c]' | math
Mathematica blah blah
Out[1]//FullForm= Plus[a, Times[b, c]]
```

Usually to avoid the "blah blah" I use "-noprompt" but here is what I get with -noprompt :

```
#  echo 'FullForm[a+b*c]' | math -noprompt
FullForm[a + b*c]
```

So my question is How to get the Correct Output ? (with noprompt)

Any advice ?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean `FullForm[Hold[1 + 1]]`?

Comment: I dunno why it answers `FullForm[Hold[1+1]]`

Comment: it seems in fact true that the behaviour is different

Comment: @chris I confirm also the problem (v.10.0.2, OS X 10.9.5). For example `echo 'FullForm[{1,2,3}]' | /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel -noprompt` returns `FullForm[{1, 2, 3}]` and not `List[1, 2, 3]` (as in the interactive mode). Same problem also if I put the command in a file e.g. "test.m" and execute `/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathematicaScript -script test.m`. In both cases, no problem if I replace the FullForm command by any other like `Plus[1,1]`.

Comment: If I try `echo 'z=a+b*c';FullForm[z] | ....` it also returns `FullForm[a + b*c]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-noprompt` switch does several things: it suppresses the `Mathematica ...` banner and all the `In`/`Out` prompts, sets the page width to `Infinity` and, most relevantly, switches the kernel default print form to `InputForm` (being preferable, in batch mode, to the regular two-dimensional typesetting used for interactive terminal sessions).

> Example : What I have : `a+b*c`
>
> What I want : `Plus[a, Times[b, c]]`

```
$ echo 'OutputForm @ FullForm[a+b*c]' | math -noprompt          
Plus[a, Times[b, c]]
```